# Pasar dato de Combobox como condicional para otro form

Tags: c#, poo

Hola a todos estoy trabajando en un proyecto de Hotel en forms, donde al momento de hacer la reserva tengo que escoger si es cliente o huesped, el cliente es el que paga la membresia del hotel y huesped es como cualquier persona regular.
Entonces al momento de seleccionar en un combobox si el cliente o huesped quiero condicionar para saber qué constructor de reserva instancia
sí es cliente o huesped, para  eso hay que saber qué valor tiene el combobox, he  estoy intentado cargar el valor a un string y no da tampoco con  static, ni public, por que lo que despues nesecitaria pasar el nombre o el objeto del cliente en la instancia de reserva

aqui tengo el codigo, alguna idea de como lo pueda solucionar?

```
public partial class VentanaCrearReserv : Form

{
    Reserva reserva;
    Recepcion recepcionHotelera;


    public VentanaCrearReserv()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void buscarhabt1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form formbuscarh = new Habitaciones();
        formbuscarh.Show();
    }

    private void Menubut1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void ButHuesped_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form formhuesped = new BuscarHuesped();
        formhuesped.Show();
    }

    private void limpiar_campos()
    {
        textBox3.Text = "";
        textBox4.Text = "";
        comboBox3.Text = "";
        dateTimePicker3.Text = "";
        dateTimePicker4.Text = "";
    }

    private void ButAgregarReserva_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, Recepcion recepcion)
    {
       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text)  String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text) 
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox3.Text)  String.IsNullOrEmpty(dateTimePicker3.Text) String.IsNullOrEmpty(dateTimePicker4.Text))
            MessageBox.Show("Revisar el contenido de los campos. Creación invalida");
        else
        {
            if ( =="Cliente")
            {
                reserva = new Reserva( , , );
                recepcionHotelera.CrearReserva(reserva);

                dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = recepcionHotelera;//////////////////Puede dar problema
                MessageBox.Show("Creación Exitosa");
                limpiar_campos();
            }
        }
```

Y este es de buscar huesped

```
string linea;
    string[] destino_split;
    Huesped huespedes;
    Cliente clientes;
    List<Huesped> listahuespedes = new List<Huesped>();
    List<Cliente> listaclientes = new List<Cliente>();


    public BuscarHuesped()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
            StreamReader archivo = new StreamReader("C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\semestre5\Poo\ArchivosHotel\Huespedes.txt");
            linea = archivo.ReadLine();
            while (!archivo.EndOfStream)
            {
                linea = archivo.ReadLine();
                destino_split = linea.Split(',');
                if (destino_split.Length >= 4)
                {
                    huespedes = new Huesped(int.Parse(destino_split[0]), destino_split[1], int.Parse(destino_split[2]), destino_split[3]);
                    listahuespedes.Add(huespedes);
                }
            }

            StreamReader archivo1 = new StreamReader("C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\semestre5\Poo\ArchivosHotel\Clientes.txt");
            linea = archivo1.ReadLine();
            while (!archivo1.EndOfStream)
            {
                linea = archivo1.ReadLine();
                destino_split = linea.Split(',');
                if (destino_split.Length >= 5)
                {
                    clientes = new Cliente(int.Parse(destino_split[0]), int.Parse(destino_split[1]), destino_split[2], int.Parse(destino_split[3]), destino_split[4]);
                    listaclientes.Add(clientes);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }

private void Butatras2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void comboBox5_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox5.Text=="Huesped")
        {

           dataGridView3.DataSource = listahuespedes;
        }
        else if (comboBox5.Text == "Cliente")
        {

            dataGridView3.DataSource = listaclientes;
        }
    }
}
```

Alguna idea? Lo agradeceria

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No entiendo donde es que tenes el problema.

Comment: @gbianchi el problema es pasar el huesped y la habitacion al constructor en el form de reserva, ya que seria pasar un objeto selesccionado de un datagridview a otro form (constructor de otro form)

Comment: donde asignas los item del `comboBox5` ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini  Los asigno en el diseño de los forms

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar el dato de un formulario a otro debes aplica esta tecnica

[Comunicar formularios](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2014/05/comunicar-formularios.html)

La idea es que puedes enviar el dato teniendo la instancia, en el evento del `VentanaCrearReserv` asignas el `this en el constructor`

```
public VentanaCrearReserv : Form {

   public string TipoCliente {get;set;}

   private void ButHuesped_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Form formhuesped = new BuscarHuesped(this);
       formhuesped.Show();
   }

}
```

De esta forma podras tener la instancia de ese form y acceder a la funcionalidad

public class BuscarHuesped : Form {

```
    private VentanaCrearReserv _frmPadre;

    public BuscarHuesped()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public BuscarHuesped(VentanaCrearReserv frmPadre) : this() {   

        _frmPadre = frmPadre;

    }

    private void Butatras2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _frmPadre.TipoCliente  = combo5.Text;
        Close();
    }

}
```

Como veras uso la propiedad `TipoCliente` implementada en el form padre para poder asignarla desde el form hijo.

En el form `BuscarHuesped` no deberias poner codigo en el constructor, para eso esta en el evento `Load`

---

Si vas a iterar un archivo por lineas es mas facil si usas el `File.ReadAllLines()` asi puede luego aplicar el `foreach`

```
string fileHuespedes = @"C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\semestre5\Poo\ArchivosHotel\Huespedes.txt";
string[] lineas = File.ReadAllLines(fileHuespedes);

foreach(string linea in lineas)
{
    string[] destino_split = linea.Split(',');
    if (destino_split.Length >= 4)
    {
        Huesped huespedes = new Huesped(int.Parse(destino_split[0]), destino_split[1], int.Parse(destino_split[2]), destino_split[3]);
        listahuespedes.Add(huespedes);
    }
}
```

Comment: estoy tratando de cambiar, pero no entiendo la parte en la que dices "En el form BuscarHuesped no deberias poner codigo en el constructor, para eso esta en el evento Load"

Comment: Oye creo que ya lo solucione pero ahora me faltaria como pasar el objeto selesccionado en el datagridview al constructor del form crear reserva, sera que porfavor me podrias indicar como hacerlo?

Comment: Si conoces los eventos del form sabras que hay un Load, es alli donde deberias poner el codigo que parsea los archivos. Habias mencionado pasa el dato seleccionado del combo, no mencionaste nada de un datagridview, igual la tecnica que deberias aplicar es la que planteo en el articulo del link